# Comparar uma váriavel com 1 é o mesmo que comparar com true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipagem

Eu possuo o seguinte código:

```
    $(function() {
    var logado = _userdata["session_logged_in"];
    if (logado == 1) {
        $('#rankPersonalizado').after('Você está logado.');
    }
});
```

Aqui:

```
if (logado == 1) {
```

`1` significa que é `true`. Especificando, se o usuário está logado.

Caso ainda não tenha sido especifico, vejam o exemplo abaixo:

```
se (logado == sim) {
```

Comment: Não dá para entender o que você está querendo. Qual é o dado que pode estar guardado em `_userdata["session_logged_in"]` . È `0` ou `1`? Tem `true` ou `false`? Tem `"sim"` ou `"não"`. Outra coisa? O que você quer fazer diferente? Por que?

Comment: Reformula a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown basicamente eu gostaria de saber o que era 0 e 1.

Comment: Não dá para saber o que você quer, o que você está dizendo não faz sentido. Detalhe o que é "saber o que era 0 e 1". Descreva passo a passo o que você deseja. E responde o que eu perguntei antes.

Comment: Certo. Repare nisto: var logado = _userdata["session_logged_in"];  está a declarar que a variável logado significa que o usuário está logado. Imagine que eu quero fazer o contrário, teria de fazer: if (logado == 0); certo? 0 significaria false e 1 significaria true?

Comment: Sim, é só isto que quer saber?

Comment: É exatamento isso.

Comment: talvez sua pergunta devesse ser "comparar uma váriavel com 1 é o mesmo que comparar com true?"

Comment: Editado. :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você dá a semântica que quiser para os valores que usa. Se tiver controle sobre o conteúdo da variável, pode até escolher o tipo de dado que deseja.

Então se prefere que a informação de `logado` já seja um booleano, guardade `true` ou `false` em `_userdata["session_logged_in"]` Aí poderá usar assim:

```
$(function() {
    var logado = _userdata["session_logged_in"];
    if (logado) {
        $('#rankPersonalizado').after('Você está logado.');
    }
});
```

Se não for usar esta variável local em outros lugares do código (no momento não está usando) e quiser simplificar:

```
$(function() {
    if (_userdata["session_logged_in"]) {
        $('#rankPersonalizado').after('Você está logado.');
    }
});
```

Se não tiver controle sobre o valor desta variável "global" que indica se o usuário está *logado*, ainda pode transformar em booleano nas demais operações:

```
$(function() {
    var logado = _userdata["session_logged_in"] == 1;
    if (logado) {
        $('#rankPersonalizado').after('Você está logado.');
    }
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/NumberIsTrue.js).

Esta forma a variável é desnecessária (se o código não for modificado e o valor for usado em outro lugar), mas ela pode ser útil para documentar o que aquilo significa. Se bem que se for para da um nome mais semântico, seria melhor usar `estahLogado`. Mas é estilo de cada um.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer a minha questão, fico grato! :)